# Opening a port with firewalld doesn't seem to work

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewalld

I have configured sshd to live on a different port. I have opened that port using firewalld:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=22000/tcp --permanent
```

Listing rules shows port 22000 is open:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --list-all
public (default)
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 22000/tcp 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

However I cannot log in from a remote host to port 22000. If I use iptables, it works:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22000 -j ACCEPT
```

I can now log in. But **how can I open the port with Firewalld**?

Edit: As requested:

```
 $ sudo firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
 public
```

And:

```
 $ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
 public
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
```

Comment: Your `public` zone is not assigned to any interface and therefore it is not effective, afaik. What is the output of `sudo firewall-cmd --get-default-zone`?

Comment: Thanks @Jakuje! Output is `public`.

Comment: Maybe more useful would be `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones` with explanation which is the network interface you are talking about.

Comment: That looks like in some non-consistent state .. however when you start playing with both `iptables` and `firewalld`, it usually stops to work. That is probably all I can say about this.

Comment: @mikemaccana Do you have both `firewalld` and `iptables` running at the same time ? Is firewall working at all ? Try removing `iptables` & `iptables-service`, reload `firewalld` and see

Comment: @Jakuje It was broken *before* I added the iptables rule, not afterwards. Deleting the iptables rule makes the port inaccessible again.

Comment: @pun 'Try removing iptables & iptables-service' - do you mean the module, the package, or something else?

Comment: @mikemaccana Yes I meant to remove the package iptables and iptables-service

Comment: @pun package iptables-service isn't installed. package iptables is required by firewalld.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the [firewalld docs](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd):

> The permanent option --permanent can be used to set options permanently. These changes are not effective immediately, only after service restart/reload or system reboot. Without the --permanent option, a change will only be part of the runtime configuration.

When using `--permanent` option, you should reload configuration by `firewall-cmd --reload`
This is because `--permanent` option writes changes to saved configuration, not into running config.

Comment: Thanks! Could you add a link to the relevant docs?

Comment: Sure. http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd    
`The permanent option --permanent can be used to set options permanently. These changes are not effective immediately, only after service restart/reload or system reboot. Without the --permanent option, a change will only be part of the runtime configuration.`